# swift how to switch background color when button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift

hello I currently have an app that flashes a random color when the button is pressed but it gets stuck in a loop and I can't change to other colors when I press the button again. I would also like to have the message disappear when the button is pressed. thank you so much !!!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let colors: [UIColor] = [
        .systemYellow,
        .systemGreen,
        .systemPurple,
        .systemPink,
        .systemRed,
        .systemBlue,
        .systemOrange,
        .black,.gray
            
        
        ]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func didTapButton() {
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1/25, delay: 0.0, options:[UIView.AnimationOptions.repeat, UIView.AnimationOptions.autoreverse], animations: {
            self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors.randomElement()
            self.view.backgroundColor = .black
            self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors.randomElement()
        }, completion: nil)
        
        
    }


}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1/25, delay: 0.0, options:[UIView.AnimationOptions.repeat, UIView.AnimationOptions.autoreverse], animations: {
             self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
             self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
             self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
             self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
             self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white        }, completion: nil)    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@IBAction func didTapButton() 
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear   // <-- reset initial background outside animation block

    // then start the animation
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1/25, delay: 0.0, options:[.autoreverse, .repeat, .allowUserInteraction], animations: { [weak self] in 
        self?.view.backgroundColor = self?.colors.randomElement()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

i.e. just set the `backgroundColor` to a random color once in the animation block.

Use `autoreverse` to return the color to the original (clear or transparent in this example).

Use the `repeat` option to repeat the animation, forever.

Use the `allowUserInteraction` to allow user interaction during the animation.

"*I would also like to have the message disappear when the button is pressed*" ... not sure what this is referring to.

Comment: thank you so much !! now the color changes every time I press the button! but how do I keep the colors flashing? the color does not flash

Comment: can you please help me flash or blink the background color forever until the button is pressed again ? then it will blink 2 new random colors

Comment: I've edited my answer based on your comments, though I'm still not 100% clear what you're trying to do